# .htaccess to load specific index file when url with 2 variable folders does not exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am updating urls of a project and have this old url: http://www.example.com/phones/nokia/

This folders `phones` and `nokia` are variable folders what don't exist anymore but I want to catch old traffic coming from them. In other words when someone visits the old url I want `.htaccess` file to load `store.php` which is located in the root directory.

How can I do this with htaccess so the url in the address bar stays `http://www.example.com/phones/nokia/` but `store.php` is still loaded.

Thank you in advance !
Thanks to Anubhava I have this code working for only 1 variable folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index\.php$ store.php [L,NC]
```

How would the code above look like for 2 variable folders? Thank you

Comment: Do not make extensive changes to the original post. It will confuse people.

Instead if you have something important to add do it by adding it bellow the existing content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one new rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index\.php$ store.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ store.php [L]
```

Comment: Man, I admire to you !Thanks !

Comment: anubhava, is it possible this directive in the htaccess : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ store.php [L] to brake ajax request? When I try to sent ajax request to a file it redirects the request to store.php file instea of returnig response from ajax call?

Comment: Working as a charm :) Thanks mate !